Ubuntu 24.04 freezing up
Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-49-generic is freezing up when I launch an app like text editing or something from the settings application.  What is the recourse to correct?

How do you know its the kernel? and not just a stuck GUI or UI (you don't specify if this is a server/text or desktop/gui install). Are you unable to direct kernel via SysRq commands?  (these bypass any stuck GUI/UI)  or are you only saying the GUI/UI seems to freeze?

Running on Dell Vostros laptop.  mouse freezes up and display frozen, also no keyboard control.  The whole machine is in a state of suspended animation.  Have to do a forced power off to restart the machine.

Did you try switching to a text terminal?   as your details thus far only indicate a possible stuck GUI (if you're talking about a desktop install; you don't specify if desktop or server clearly). Did you try giving the kernel a direct command (bypassing your UI; ie. even if screen frozen, you could ask machine to safely restart using SysRq-REISUB for example).  If it's kernel panic (ie. kernel crashes) there will be no system log entries; but if a UI freezes the log entries will continue until you force power off; have you explored this?

This question is similar to: How can I boot with an older kernel version?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
